# FileStreamResult does not return a body

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to bring a file on a roundtrip through an IIS7.

I got my action method as follows:

```
public ActionResult GiveItBack()
{
    var inFile = Request.Files[0];
    var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.GetTempPath() + "uploadedFile.tif", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    inFile.InputStream.Position = 0;
    inFile.InputStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    return new FileStreamResult(fileStream, "image/tiff");
}
```

I call it with fiddler, file is uploaded and created on the server, but fiddler shows a "response has no body" message instead of the image (file is indead a tif). Raw response is

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: image/tiff
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcQXJiZWl0c2JlcmVpY2hcUHJvamVrdGUgLSBmcmVtZFxBbXBzMyBQaXBlc1xLaXR0ZWxiZXJnZXIuQU1QUzMuV2ViU2VydmljZVxDb21tYW5kQ2hhaW5cRG9pbmc=?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 14 Jun 2017 12:48:22 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

As you can see the content length is zero. Why is the image not coming back?

Comment: Do you need to save the file on disk or you just want it back?

Comment: @Magnus this is a simplification of a larger action, in this it will be saved on disk

Comment: Reset `fileStream.Position = 0;` before your return as the `CopyTo` will have writen to it and moved the pointer to the end of that stream.

Comment: You might also consider flushing the stream.

Comment: @Igor *with all the dignity I can muster up* Thank you. Please write an answer, so you get the fame.

Comment: @Sebastian - No problem, glad to help. I added the answer with 2 other points as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reset the Position of the `fileStream` instance back to 0 before returning it in the result.

From [CopyTo documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932(v=vs.110).aspx)

> #### Remarks
>
> Copying begins at the current position in the current stream, and does not reset the position of the destination stream after the copy operation is complete.

Also add a `try/catch` to dispose of the `FileStream` if there is an exception and then rethrow.

*Code with changes*

```
public ActionResult GiveItBack()
{
    var inFile = Request.Files[0];
    var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.GetTempPath() + "uploadedFile.tif", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    try {
        inFile.InputStream.Position = 0;
        inFile.InputStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        fileStream.Position = 0;
        return new FileStreamResult(fileStream, "image/tiff");
    } catch {
        fileStream.Dispose();
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Settings the Position will flush the stream.